# static analysis weird sign behavior with mixed C and C++ code

Tags: c++, c, static-analysis

Given the following definitions in a mixed C and C++ program:

```
//in a C file.
uint8_t GetSize()
{
return (uint8_t)something;
}

//in the header of the C++ file.

public:
  MyClass(){};
private:
  uint8_t index_m;
```

Both of the following lines give me a static tool (pc-lint) [warning 573](https://www.gimpel.com/html/bugs/bug573.htm).

```
void MyClass::IncrementWithRollOver(void)
{
        index_m = (index_m + 1) % GetSize(); // warning 573 : signed-unsigned mix with divide
}
void MyClass::DecrementWithRollOver(void)
{
        index_m = (GetSize() - 1 + index_m) % GetSize(); // warning 573 : signed-unsigned mix with divide
}
```

I tried lots of casting but none is helping me getting rid of this warning, why?

```
        index_m = (index_m + 1U) % GetSize(); // this one works

        index_m = (GetSize() - 1U + index_m) % GetSize();// info 834: operator '-' followed by operator '+' could be confusing without parentheses [MISRA 2004 Rule 12.1, advisory]

        index_m = (uint8_t)(index_m + (uint8_t)1) % GetSize(); // warning 573 : signed-unsigned mix with divide, and: info 732: loss of sign (assignment) ('int' to 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char')

        index_m = (uint8_t)(GetSize() - (uint8_t)1 + index_m) % GetSize(); // warning 573 : signed-unsigned mix with divide, and: info 834: operator '-' followed by operator '+' could be confusing without parentheses [MISRA 2004 Rule 12.1, advisory]

        index_m = (uint8_t)(index_m + (uint16_t)1) % GetSize(); // warning 573 : signed-unsigned mix with divide, and: info 732: loss of sign (assignment) ('int' to 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char')

        index_m = (uint8_t)(GetSize() - (uint16_t)1 + index_m) % GetSize(); // warning 573 : signed-unsigned mix with divide, and: info 834: operator '-' followed by operator '+' could be confusing without parentheses [MISRA 2004 Rule 12.1, advisory]
```

what a pain in the ... C!

What's the quick fix for this?

---

After reading the comments I also unsuccessfully tried

```
     index_m = (uint8_t)(index_m + (uint32_t)1) % GetSize(); // works

     index_m = (uint8_t)(GetSize() - (uint32_t)1 + index_m) % GetSize(); // info 834: operator '-' followed by operator '+' could be confusing without parentheses [MISRA 2004 Rule 12.1, advisory]
```

this get me rid of the sign/unsigned mix problem but this "operator '-' followed by operator '+'" is still weird!

Comment: This is part of the reason you should use an `int` or larger type.  everything smaller than an `int` is converted to an `int`/`unsigned int` for built in operations.

Comment: i tried also with uint16_t which is larger thant uint8_t. and same warning.

Comment: in a 32 bit machine a `int` would be a `int32_t`.  If you want unsigned then `uint32_t` would be the smallest type that has built in operators.

Comment: Because `uint16_t` is smaller than `int` (and `unsigned int`)…

Comment: @GuillaumeD The comments are about the type of `index_m`.  You need that to be an `uint32_t`.  Then you won't get any warnings as all the math will be done as a `uint32_t`.

Comment: Given the warning from `index_m = (GetSize() - 1U + index_m) % GetSize();`, did you experiment with `index_m = (GetSize() + index_m - 1U) % GetSize();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the quick fix for this?

Simplest is:

```
 index_m = (index_m + 1U) % GetSize(); // this one works
```

> ok for incrementation but the problem is with the decrementation...
>
> ```
> index_m = (GetSize() - 1U + index_m) % GetSize();// info 834: operator '-' followed by operator '+' could be confusing without parentheses [MISRA 2004 Rule 12.1, advisory]
> ```

Note that this is only an info message; not a warning. But regardless, the solution to lack of parentheses is to add parentheses:

```
index_m = ((GetSize() - 1U) + index_m) % GetSize();
```

<sub>Or, apparently change order of operations to `(GetSize() + index_m - 1U)`, as found out in comments</sub>

Comment: isn't what I do in the line "index_m = (uint8_t)(index_m + (uint8_t)1) % GetSize();" ?

Comment: @GuillaumeD I changed suggestion.

Comment: @GuillaumeD: Note that `1U` is an `unsigned int`; `(uint8_t)1` is promoted to a signed `int`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I had different suggestion initially. Comment is about that

Comment: My comment is about the code in the comment from Guillaume D; it uses `(uint8_t)1` and that is a signed `int` value.  However, if you're convinced my comment is unhelpful (or "comments are unhelpful"), flag it 'no longer needed' and I'll hide my chagrin in a blizzard of comments to other questions and answers.

Comment: (GetSize()  + index_m - 1U) works as well... silly :D

Comment: @GuillaumeD It's not quite as easy to misinterpret that order of operations. I wouldn't have guessed that the static analyser was so nuanced.

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++, integers that are smaller than an `int` are *promoted* to an integer with same sign and as large as an `int` as soon as you use them in an operation (`+`...).

This is historical and a bit confusing, but I guess the original intent was to limit the risk of *overflow* on computations with small integers.

In `index_m + 1`, `index_m` will be promoted to `unsigned int` then the sign mismatch with `1` which is a `signed int`.

So you will have to *cast* anyway after the operation is done (depending on warning level).